# OpenCV: unresolved external symbol cv::Algorithm

Tags: opencv, linker, linker-errors

I know there is simply a .lib missing in my linker options. But which one? Where is cv::Algorithm contained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it is simply opencv_core24x.lib :-)